# Which form-builder handles many-to-many relationships of data and dynamic input?

Tags: ajax, perl, dancer

I'm experimenting with [Dancer](http://perldancer.org) some time, and looking for the right blocks to build my application. Frameworks tend to have flat example applications, dealing with one table at time. So I have no good idea  which tools should be used to build a little bit more complex CRUD forms.

Let's say I create a Booklovers app. It should have a form to add/edit books **with** authors. To cover this I need 3 tables in our database: `books`, `authors` and `books_to_authors`. Which is best way to build a form to add a book with authors?

Note:

- It is not known how many authors a book may have, we need dynamic adding of rows.
- The `authors` table may have tens of thousands of records, so a `select` form element is not suitable.
- An author may be missing from our database, we need to add them dynamically, too.

All these dynamic parts needs some AJAX. Is there a good solution to integrate it with form creating tools in Perl? I looked at [CGI::FormBuilder](http://p3rl.org/CGI%3a%3aFormBuilder) and am still looking, but I did not find something that could build forms for 3 joined tables as described. The dynamic client-side part also still needs to be covered.

Are there some best practices for such a pretty simple case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is somehow too complex question to have straightforward solution.

I stick using templates forms and generete dynamic part with different jQuery plugins.

I don't think it is best way, but have not seen better for now.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is for rendering data in a Web browser, it doesn't affect the back-end data storage.

The `books` and `authors` tables have a [many-to-many relationship, using ORMs such as DBIx-Class](http://p3rl.org/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aCookbook#Many-to-many_relationships) can help.

In the Web form, there is a new `book` and a collection of `authors`. At the server side, create a `book`, then add `authors` to `book`.

Browse the [DBIx::Class cookbook](http://p3rl.org/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aCookbook) to get some ideas.

Sorry for not providing a simple answer to solve your problem.

Comment: I think AJAX is important thing to consider when you chose your building blocks. Some already have very good bindings (like `CGI::FormBuilder`), so it makes your app more solid. I avoided ORM, because i looked DBIx couple of years ago and had troubles with this (unicode support and joining tables from multiple databases). Still, i will look it again. Thank you!

Comment: Adjustment: `CGI::FormBuilder` has javascript bindings, not directly to some AJAX library, AFAIK.

Comment: It seems you are seasoned programmer. Would you consider nosql? Build the forms yourself may more efficient than us a form tool tool to bind sql into a form. Use a minimal framework such as mojolicios http://mojolicious.org/ make things easier. You could also have a look at CGI::Ajax.

Comment: I agree that it would be nice to have a walkthrough or demo code for a use-case like this. @w.k.: what did you end up using?

Comment: @spazm: i'm still stickin' around. I've some thoughts to build something more general, but have not get picture together. Like it is always: not enough time. I still build forms by hand, nothing fancier.